# How does one measure the handedness of quarks considering that they don't exist freely?

Tags: quantum-spin, measurements, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, chirality

Question is fairly straightforward as stated: How does one measure the handedness of quarks considering that they don't exist freely?

Comment: Not that straightforward: why do you mean by measure? Quark chiralities flip-flop all the time on act of their masses. A W  which only couples to left-chiral quarks will access and transform only half the partons of that kind at any given time. Are you asking a question about partons in neutrino scattering?